# Do "older friends" mean senior friends?

Tags: meaning

Do "older friends" mean senior friends here?

> S: Um...I'm thinking of going to Central University, because it's in my hometown. I've uh, been kind of homesick here this year, and I haven't made many friends...I just feel so lonely. So, I thought that uh, maybe, it'd be better to be closer to my parents and friends and all.
>   S: Yeah, I know that. But I'm a little bit familiar with Central, 'cuz I had **older friends** who went there, and I visited it before I came here.

Comment: What do you mean by senior?  Older friends, means just that- friends whose age is greater than his own.

Comment: I thought that "older friends" could mean the friends who he had known from his early age (ex: 0-15 years old) and the friends were the same age as him.

Answer (score 2):

There are three more-or-less likely possibilities for *older* with regards to friends:

- physically older than me
- physically older than my other friends
- known to me for a longer period of time than my other friends (in this sense, 'older' is opposed to 'newer', not 'younger')

In the context given, however, it should be clear that going to study at a university is something that normally happens at a given age (normally when one is 18 in the US), and the speaker is getting ready to choose a university to attend.  Therefore the only friends who could have already attended the university are ones who are physically older than him; the other two possible meanings have no bearing on the friends' ability to attend a university.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is correct. 'S' is talking about his older friends (friends that older than him), that studied in Central University.